# .Net - Detect if desired identifier is a keyword

Tags: .net, code-generation

Is there a way, in .net, to detect if a word is a keyword in a given .net language?

I am using a fairly simple code generator for this project, and I would like to start automating it.  Right now I do each one by hand, so fixing any issues that arise is pretty easy.  However, once this starts happening automatically I am going to need a way to detect if a word I need to use as an identifier is a keyword.  I can still use it, I just need to quote it properly.

I know that I can simply quote *everything* I generate, but I would like to keep the generated code pretty :)

An example of the kind of things I need to quote:

```
vb:  Public [Class] As String = "CLASS"
c#:  public String @class = "CLASS";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [`IsValidIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.isvalididentifier.aspx)

> [`IsValidIdentifier`] return[s] true
>   only if the value fits the rules of
>   the language and **does not conflict
>   with a keyword**.

or [`CreateEscapedIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.createescapedidentifier.aspx)

> `CreateEscapedIdentifier` tests **whether
>   the identifier conflicts with any
>   reserved or language keywords**, and if
>   so, returns an equivalent name with
>   language-specific escape code
>   formatting

For example:

```
    CSharpCodeProvider csProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

    bool isValid1 = csProvider.IsValidIdentifier("class");
    // returns false

    string escapedId1 = csProvider.CreateEscapedIdentifier("foo");
    // escapedId1 = "foo"
    string escapedId2 = csProvider.CreateEscapedIdentifier("do");
    // escapedId2 = "@do"
    string escapedId3 = csProvider.CreateEscapedIdentifier("AndAlso");
    // escapedId3 = "AndAlso" (not reserved in c#)

    VBCodeProvider vbProvider = new VBCodeProvider();

    string escapedId4 = vbProvider.CreateEscapedIdentifier("AndAlso");
    // escapedId4  = "[AndAlso]" (reserved in VB)
```

Seems like it wouldn't be too hard to extend/use this facility to meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

[See here](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/730472-c-keyword-list-programatically). Man, Jon Skeet is everywhere!

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) already take care of this? You could build your generated code that way and automatically get support for any language which supports CodeDOM.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any natural way to do this programmatically, but you can get a full list of keywords for C# [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb(vs.71).aspx), and for VB.Net [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(VS.71).aspx).